# Create Pie Chart Using JSON Data React

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-google-charts

I have one Array that consist of one Key called Status it has two value 1 is good and other is bad i am using react-google-charts i upload my code below kindly check and help me

JSON:

```
[
    {
        Status: 'Good'
    },
    {
        Status: 'Bad'
    },
    {
        Status: 'Bad'
    },
    {
        Status: 'Good'
    },
    {
        Status: 'Good'
    },
    {
        Status: 'Bad'
    },
    {
        Status: 'Good'
    }
]
```

My React Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from 'react-google-charts';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class chart extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/items').then(response => this.setState({ items: response.data }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Chart
                    width={'500px'}
                    height={'300px'}
                    chartType="PieChart"
                    loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                    data={[['Task', 'Status of Items'], ['Good', 4], ['Bad', 3]]}
                    options={{
                        title: 'Item Status'
                    }}
                    rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Currently i'm hardcoded the value here:

```
    data={[
        ['Task', 'Status of Items'],
        ['Good', 4],
        ['Bad', 3],
      ]}
```

I want to add the no of good and bad on above code using API i try to find length of array but it didn't work it finds whole array value not either good or bad. kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can `reduce` to get the **Good** and **Bad** counts to a single `JSON` and then use `Object.entries` to get the required format as in an array.

Try like this

```
<Chart
    width={'500px'}
    height={'300px'}
    chartType="PieChart"
    loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
    data={[
        ['Task', 'Status of Items'],
        ...Object.entries(
            this.state.items.reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
                prevValue[currValue.Status] =
                    prevValue[currValue.Status] === undefined ? 1 : prevValue[currValue.Status] + 1;
                return prevValue;
            }, {})
        )
    ]}
    options={{
        title: 'Item Status'
    }}
    rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
/>
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-wind-1bizj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Karthikeyan M, check this out !!